# Stokes Theorem: Unit Ball

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds

Given the unit ball:
$$M:=\mathbb{B}:\quad\partial M=\varnothing$$

Consider the top-degree form:
$$\omega:=1\mathrm{d}x\wedge\mathrm{d}y=\mathrm{d}(x\mathrm{d}y)=:\mathrm{d}\Omega$$

Then one has by Stoke's theorem:
$$\pi=\int_\mathbb{B}1=\int_\varnothing\Omega=0$$
But where is the flaw??

Comment: $\partial M=\phi$ has null measure hence $\int_{\partial M} \omega=0$, I guess..

Comment: Integrating over an empty set gives $0$; how much area is there under nothing?

Comment: Well, think of a sphere. You can cover it by two hemispheres with boundary, integrating along the sphere is the same as integrating over the two hemispheres, but the orientation is reversed (such that the hemispheres are  glued preserving orientation), so you integrate over the boundary, minus the same integral over the boundary.

Comment: The Stokes theorem applies to compact (orientable) manifolds, if my guess is correct that $B_1(0)$ is some open unit ball in $\Bbb R^2$, then it fails compactness, and your integral will be nonzero (equal to the area of the ball).

Comment: I know that simply Stoke's theorem applies but I don't *understand* why this makes sense. I mean just look at the example: Would you confirm that being zero?

Comment: @OlivierBégassat I don't think this is a problem, because the boundary of the ball has null measure, so the integral can be prolonged to the closed ball.

Comment: The problem in your intuition is that you're thinking about a 3 dimensional manifold. Can you understand for the 2 dimensional case? It is pretty much the same for higher dimensions.

Comment: @user40276 I'm just trying to correct a (I think) misapplication of Stokes theorem.

Comment: If you wanted to apply the theorem to your example, you'd have to consider the compact manifold with boundary $\overline{B_1}$. Then by Stokes formula, $$\mathrm{Area}(\overline{B_1})=\int_{\overline{B_1}}dx\wedge dy=\int_{\partial \overline{B_1}}i^*(x\,dy)$$ where $i:\partial(\overline{B_1})\hookrightarrow \overline{B_1}$ is the inclusion of the boundary circle in the disk.

Comment: The closed ball has a boundary, it's the sphere. Do you know the definition of a manifold with boundary?

Comment: Ok I just checked Lee: the form must be compactly supported - but then there's still the problem for some bump function...

Comment: Even if it´s not compactly supported you can integrate it, you just cannot guarantee the convergence, if it converges and there is a triangulation Stokes theorem will hold.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the form is not compactly-supported.

Also as soon as one introduces a positive bump it fails to have a primitive.